# Is it true that http requests via proxy cannot be detected and blocked by the target server?

Tags: proxy, http, blocking

In the situation in which a server A sends http requests via php under proxy to server B is it real that server B can't know that the requests are sent by a proxy? And if server B administrator is sure that server A is sending requests under proxy what could he do to block server A requests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no. It depends.

First the "Yes". If all request are received at server B via the proxy then all that [web]-server will see if the proxies IP.

Next, the "No". Some proxy do add an extra header with the IP of the originating host. In that case server B knows who he is talking to and can act on it.

So, it depends on the configuration. And in real life things get messier because webpages sometimes can run plugins (if not properly configured to block those, which seems to be needed to survive today's Internet). In that case a script can run and get some unique information on the source computer. E.g. its IP adresses, or its MAC addresses, or the CPU-ID, ...

All in all there is no single "Yes" or "no" answer to this and there are many ways to expand this answer with even more 'maybe if ...' parts.